# ListView with an empty SelectedItems , when DoubleClick handler is called

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a `WinForm` app that has a `ListView` in it, with a `DoubleClick` event handler assigned to it. 
Theoretically , only items are "clickable" , so it should be impossible to enter the event handler with  no selected items, and so it is for 99% of cases. 
However, every once in a while, I catch an exception of `InvalidAgrument` as my handler try to access `list_view.SelectedItems[0]`, and there I see that it does actually empty.

When  I try to reproduce, it takes an aggressive clicking session to do it. But it's done, I can sometimes see the cursor in the middle of a valid entity , which makes me suspect it might be some racing condition.

Comment: Of course it's possible, you're catching mouse clicks...did you try to simply double click in the background area? Where there are not any items?

Comment: I've aome across this as well. Guessing the doubleclick event for the ListView gets fired when you click inside that,but not on any particular item..

Comment: @Adriano that's the point. clicking inside the `ListView` but not on an entity does NOT fire the handler (I've checked that many times, I even tried to click in between items) , and when I finally reproduce, as the GUI freezes I can clearly see that last click was on a valid item.

Comment: @JimLanflte my fault, you're right! I always checked SelectedItems for "emptiness" sure that that even may fire with a double click in the background!!! Good to know...

Comment: @JimLanflte you may find it useful to study the stack trace (or the call stack) when you get this `InvalidArgument` exception.  I'd say that when you double click an unselected item the `ListView` must do some work to change/set the selected item then raise the `DoubleClick` event.  Sometimes under heavy load eg. fast selection changes and double clicks these can get out of sync (see lost items on the Win32 message queue).  You may get a non-empty `SelectedItems` but a selected item not the same as what was double clicked.

Comment: To allow time for select+doubleclick to get in sync you could use a delegate to handle the event asynchronously.

Comment: @JimLanflte where is your code? We hardly can tell you what to do

Comment: @JimLanflte with your description, I can't reproduce it because it works OK for me, when double clicking any item, the `SelectedItems[0]` is always identifiable.

Answer (score 2):

This can certainly go wrong, a double-click doesn't guarantee that an item is selected.  It may also *de-select* an item, your code will crash.  Short from adding the test to check that SelectedItems isn't empty, the possible better mouse trap is to find the exact item that was double-clicked.  Use the MouseDoubleClick event instead so you get the mouse position, then use the ListView.HitTest() method.  Like this:

```
    private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        var item = ((ListView)sender).HitTest(e.Location);
        if (item != null) {
            // etc..
        }
    }
```